# What is the procedure to deploy visual studio 2008 web application on azure cloud?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, azure-webapps

Our web application is built in visual studio 2008. Is it possible to host it in IIS on azure virtual machine? What is the procedure?

I only see articles on vs 2010 and higher.